# Matlab IMAQ generates black image (no image) for my GigE camera

Tags: matlab, camera

I'm having an issue with my GigE camera whenever I'm doing image acquisition with MATLAB IMAQ. It is clearly connected as indicated by the gigecamlist and gigecam function calls, but the issue is I'm always having black images or you can say no image at all. I figured it might be an issue of the frame size.Also, my network adapter doesn't provide the option of choosing jumbo frames, so I'm not sure what I can do about it now. The camera model under question is JAI Pulnix 1405-GE and I'm using MATLAB 2014b.

If any of you have any clue about what the problem might be, please share it with me. If you can give me some clue about what I can do solve this issue, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you need to change camera exposure value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the JAI SDK software to see if the camera works properly?
Once you are sure about it working, copy the parameters shown in JAI SDK to your Matlab camera object.

On a side note, GigE cameras work better with Labview.